# Unable to produce padding between divs using css circles

Tags: html, css

**UPDATE**

Arnab Chatterjee, Vikram, sbeliv01 were all correct. Another thing I did wrong was positioning the icon text with *top* rather than *margin-top*. Luke pointed out that using top positioned it outside the container.

---

I have a set of divs that contain a circle drawn by CSS. The divs automatically realign themselves depending on the width of the browser (I'm using the mix it up library). However the text I've written underneath the Circles overlap the circles beneath them when aligned on top of each other. I attempted to add padding to the circles but that just managed to make the circles bigger. Is there a way I can add padding to each of these divs so they do not overlap themselves when positioned on top of each other?

Here is my attempt below

https://jsfiddle.net/p5moyg6g/2/

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mix iconcircle"><div class="icontext">Icon 1</div></div>
        <div class="mix iconcircle"><div class="icontext">Icon 2</div></div>
        <div class="mix iconcircle"><div class="icontext">Icon 3</div></div>
        <div class="mix iconcircle"><div class="icontext">Icon 4</div></div>

    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mixitup/latest/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('.container').mixItUp();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
   background:black;
}

.container{
   padding:50px;
}
.container:after{
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   padding-bottom:50px;
}
.mix{
   color:white;

}

.iconcircle{
   background-color: rgba(204, 0,102,0);
   border: 4px solid #FFF;
   height: 180px;
   width: 180px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   -moz-border-radius: 100px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
}

.icontext{
   position:relative;
   width:180px;
   text-align:center;
   top:200px;

}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you positioned the text so they're not actually inside the circle. Padding also refers to the space between the text inside and the boundaries of an element, whereas margin is the spacing between other elements. Margins were probably what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `margin-bottom` to the `.iconcircle` class to add some spacing between the circles.

https://jsfiddle.net/p5moyg6g/4/

```
.iconcircle{
    background-color: rgba(204, 0,102,0);
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The issue with that, is the code handling the responsiveness breaks. And it just displays everything in one column no matter the browser width.

Comment: The fiddle wasn't set up properly as far as including the jQuery library + plugin. Please see updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p5moyg6g/4/. Is this not the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the class:

```
    .mix.iconcircle {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: That solution breaks the responsiveness, and only displays everything in one column.

Answer (score 1):

You should use margin/margin-bottom as **padding is space between border and content**. and in your case you are using border and border-radius to make it circular which means whatever you use in padding you are just expanding you boundaries not spacing between elements

you should use following instead

```
.iconcircle{
    background-color: rgba(204, 0,102,0);
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    margin-bottom : 15px;
}
```